# Google Places API autocomplete performance becomes progressively slower

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a webpage that uses the google places and google maps API on the same page. A user selects a certain location from google places autocomplete and the google map then centers on that given place.

The logic of this event seems to work fine, however I've noticed that 1.) 'autocomplete' place suggestions become slower and slower with each additional place searched through the search bar, and 2.) the shadow on the place suggestions becomes darker and darker with each additional search (see pictures below).

This problem seems to be 'reset' once the browser cache is cleared, leading me to believe the issue is that the previous search terms in the input box are being stored somewhere and slowing down the google places performance.

I apologize if this is a simple issue, but googling the past few days on this problem has turned up nothing for me. Any help??

View of the search box before any problems:
[image]

Search bar after multiple previous searches:
[image]

My initMap() function:
    function initMap() {

```
        var myLatLng = {lat: 40, lng: -20}; //display the initial main map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bigMainMap'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoom: 3
        });

        var searchTerm = $('#mainAdvSearchBox')[0];
        var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchTerm);         

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': chosenArea}, function(results, status) {  //use google place bounds to appropriately zoom on street/city/country
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
                        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', setSelectedMarkers); 
                }
                else
                    setAllMarkers(); //user has directly navigated to adventures page, show world map and all events     
        });
}
```

My tag for including the google apis:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: can you add your html codes? are you using jquery?

Comment: it would be great if you could send a sample in jsbin or jsfiddle just like what i did on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by a mistake in implementation. This normally happens when

`new google.maps.places.Autocomplete`

is added inside the input's `keyup` event listener like this:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  // this is where things starts to go wrong
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  });
}
```

Check out the wrong implementation here: http://jsbin.com/popucap/edit?js,output

The listener part for the input box is unnecessary. This will make your autocomplete go insane. The autocomplete will pile itself on the previous suggestions again and again. because every time you input a character, the autocomplete is being created again.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  // this is how it should be
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
```

Check out the working sample here: http://jsbin.com/cubirod/edit?js,output

If this is not how you're doing it, you should get an idea of how this happens with my samples. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, unfortunately my issue is still happening. I've added (I think) the relevant code, maybe you can spot something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Brandon did you find any solution i face the same problem